# How to select all distinct values except one in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query in PHP where I am getting all distinct values and then getting the sums of associated columns of these distinct values  like this:

```
SELECT t.`fruits`,sum(coalesce(s.amount,0)),sum(coalesce(s.price,0))
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT `fruits` FROM `accouts`) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` s
 ON(t.`fruits` = s.`fruits` AND s.`userid` = 1
AND s.`date` BETWEEN "2010-11-01" AND "2015-12-22")
GROUP BY t.`fruits`
```

How can I exclude a certain distinct value from this query? Specifically if the "fruits" column is empty? Because this returns data like this:

```
Oranges - 23 - 43
Pears   - 33 - 55
        - 12 - 13
Grapes  - 54 - 76
```

I want to exclude the distinct row where "fruits" is empty. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Did you tried adding a `WHERE` condition on that field? `WHERE t.fruits IS NOT NULL` or `WHERE t.fruits <> ""` ?

Comment: add : AND t.`fruits` is not NULL - in the where Clause

Comment: Add AND t.fruits IS NOT NULL

Comment: I was using my WHERE clause before the join, should I use it after the join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.`fruits`,sum(coalesce(s.amount,0)),sum(coalesce(s.price,0))
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT `fruits` FROM `accouts`) t
LEFT OUTER JOIN `accounts` s
 ON(t.`fruits` = s.`fruits` AND s.`userid` = 1
AND s.`date` BETWEEN "2010-11-01" AND "2015-12-22")
WHERE t.`fruits` != ''
GROUP BY t.`fruits`
```

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! Can you please explain to me why you can't add the WHERE clause before the join?

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you :)

Comment: but you can add the WHERE at the end of the DISTINCT query - ... FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `fruits` FROM `accouts WHERE `fruits` != '' )